# How to combine each and then

Tags: jquery, ajax, soap, locking

I'm trying to make soap request inside `.each()` but jQuery executes the next object (in the list) before the first soap request finished. How can I put a lock on it ?

For example:

```
$(xmlHttpRequest.responseXML).find("Items").find("PowerPlant").each(function(index, item){      
    sendSOAPRequest(item);
});
```

Comment: It's about the callback.  Can you show us `sendSOAPRequest()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what library you are using, but in some of the `sendSOAPRequest` calls in some of the versions you should be able to set an `async` variable to false, thus forcing them to be executed one at a time:

```
$(xmlHttpRequest.responseXML).find("Items").find("PowerPlant").each(function(index, item){      
    sendSOAPRequest(item, {async: false}); //Might be other syntax. Look at the doc for your library.
});
```

If this does not work, you can do as Brad M suggests:

```
items = $(xmlHttpRequest.responseXML).find("Items").find("PowerPlant");           

function sendSoapReq(itemList){
    if(itemList.length > 0)
    {
        sendSOAPRequest(itemList.splice(0,1), function(){
            sendSoapReq(itemList);
        });
    }
}

sendSoapReq(items);
```

Comment: oh my god... Shame on me !
I used $.ajax & i miss the asyn attributes :(

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Making the request synchronous will "lock" the browser, which is generally an undesirable behavior. Using async and callbacks is the preferred solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the next iteration of the $.each loop inside of the soap request's complete callback function.